# Could not find any resources appropriate for the culture or the neutral culture error after upgrading to VS2017

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have an assembly which includes only custom controls. I've upgraded the project from VS2015 to VS2017 by replacing the old `.csproj` file with the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I then opened the project again and added any references which where missing (System.Design and System.Windows.Forms). I've also deleted `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

I then setup the Package information in the Properties tab and built a nuget package, published and consumed in my WinForms app. Note that in the package information tab I set the `Assembly neutral language` to `invariant` but after closing and opening the properties tab, it reverts back to `none`. I've also set it to a specific language.

This assembly has its own `resources.resx` file and it's set to `Embedded resource`. Some user controls also have a separate `resx` file and they're also set to `Embedded resource`.

However, when opening a form that uses one or more of my custom controls, I get the error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the culture or the neutral culture. Make sure 'ControlsAssembly.MyControl.resources' was correctly embedded or linked into assembly 'ControlsAssembly' at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Note that when the project was still in the VS2015 and I published a package, everything worked fine. The problem started immediately after the project upgrade to VS2017.

Also not that in VS2017 the `MyControl.designer.cs` and 'MyControl.resx' files are located at the same level as the `MyControl.cs` instead of below it.

What is wrong with the project? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same problem when converting an old .net project to sdk project style.
The source and explanation: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4488.
With vs 2017 I am afraid, that the only solution is to add:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Form1.resx">
    <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

to your csproj for every problematic form. *Remember to use relative path, if forms are in sub folders...*

As for vs2019, you can try: change to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`
and use `<EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>true</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>`. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/msbuild).